# slapd.conf ACL: ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I am trying to limit write access to users own `userPassword` attribute. But failing miserably for hours now. Here is what I've done so far:

- Installed OpenLDAP 2.4 on Arch linux
- Configured a base DN (`dc=exmaple,dc=org`) and a Manager to modify,add and delete via Apache Directory Studio
- Added two organizationalUnit's `people` and `group`
- Added two users under `ou=people` - `uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org` and `uid=heike,...`

The next thing I am wanting to do is to be able to modify the users own userPassword. For that I created a `changepw.ldif` file.

```
dn: uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: newpw
```

and applied it like this

```
$ ldapmodify -x -D "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -W -f changepw.ldif
modifying entry "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

*I've set the userPassword for uid=timo with Apache Directory Studio first and verified that it's working correctly*

To this point everything is working as it should (at least it meet my expectations :-P). So I've added an access control to /etc/openldap/slapd.conf like so:

```
[...]
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

access  to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=org" write by * none

#######################################################################
# MDB database definitions

database        mdb
[...]
```

and did the usual things:

```
$ slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
$ chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d
$ systemctl restart slapd
```

and tried again.

```
$ ldapmodify -x -D "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -W -f changepw.ldif
modifying entry "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

For some reason the access gets denied. I've turn on acl logging and got this:

```
5f12f36a => access_allowed: result not in cache (userPassword)
5f12f36a => access_allowed: auth access to "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" "userPassword" requested
5f12f36a => slap_access_allowed: backend default auth access granted to "(anonymous)"
5f12f36a => access_allowed: auth access granted by read(=rscxd)
5f12f36a => access_allowed: backend default write access denied to "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution after I found out that there is a tool called `slapacl` to test the ACL.

Let me show you what it looked like before any changes.

```
$ slapacl -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -b "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -D "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -u userPassword
authcDN: "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"
userPassword: read(=rscxd)
```

That is basically what I already figured and gave me enough evidence to question the config generation command (`slaptest -f ... -F ...`).

**The actual problem was that the configuration directory (`/etc/openldap/slapd.d`) wasn't overriden**

You have to remove that directory first and generate the configuration directory again.

```
$ rm -rf /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*
$ slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
$ chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d
$ systemctl restart slapd
```

And this is how the test should've looked like in the first place.

```
$ slapacl -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -b "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -D "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" -u userPassword
authcDN: "uid=timo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org"
userPassword: write(=wrscxd)
```

I hope someone can benefit from my findings. Its still curious that this is not mentioned in the man pages and that there is no `-f` (force override) flag for that.